# How to find position of character in a list with respect to other characters in a list in o(n) time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I have a string `PRIME` on a list `['P','R','I','M','E']`. If we iterate through the list, the first element `'P'` has 3 elements less than it which is `['I','M','E']` and the second element `'R'` has only three elements less than it (note that we are looking for smaller elements going forward in the list so while looking for elements smaller than `'R'`, `'P'` would not be considered as we are done with it) so the positional list would be `[3,3,1,1,0]` in above example. I could do this in `o(n**2)` time by using a nested loop but is there any way to do this in `o(n)`? I tried something like this but it failed horribly:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):

x=list(input())

y=sorted(x)
lis=[]
for _ in x:
    res=abs(y.index(_)-x.index(_))
    lis.append(res)


print(lis)
```

Comment: This seem to be a programming assignment. however I have a hint for you, first of all sort the input, `O(nlogn)`, then see if you can infer something from the previous indices and new indices ?

Comment: @downvoter  I think i have explained my problem to the best i could,also i have explained my approach but it looks like it is a tradition to down vote the question here when someone doesn't know about it

Comment: @ZdaR Nope,i am trying to find the rank of a word in a dict (permutation concept) and for that i need this ,although my script works correctly it is slow hence the problem

Comment: If you really wanna do it in `O(n)`, then it would require some more efforts, to save the sorting time you can assume that characters are soretd in order `["a", "b", "c", ... "y", "z"]`, and then maintain a data structure, which would mark the preceeded words for each `abcd` wrt input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is mine (not O(n), but not O(n^2) either I guess):

```
>>> def find_dict_position(s):
        from collections import defaultdict
        counter = defaultdict(int)
        result = []
        less_count = 0
        for e in s[::-1]:
            less_count = sum(counter[c] for c in counter if c<e)
            result.append(less_count)
            counter[e] += 1
        return reversed(result)

>>> list(find_dict_position('PRIME'))
[3, 3, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Well, if the list is a list of characters, then this _is_ in fact O(n)... more precisely it is bounded by O(26*n), and since 26 is a constant factor, it can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether if you can do this in a smaller complexity or not, you can use a list comprehension and a generator expression as follows to make your code faster and more Pythonic.

```
In [7]: [sum(j > t for t in lst[i+1:])for i, j in enumerate(lst)]
Out[7]: [3, 3, 1, 1, 0]
```

Also, Note that you cannot do this in O(n), because after all you need to compare your elements together which is a sorting type algorithm that in best case can be done in O(nlong(n)).

Answer (score 0):

So basically this problem is finding the count of smaller elements on the right side of current position in an array. First replace character array with their respective ASCII values. That you can use balanced BST to solve the problem.

[Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-smaller-elements-on-right-side/) is the detailed explanation for the finding count of smaller elements on the right side in an array . Complexity O(nLogn).

But here as array elements are only characters it can be done in O(n) complexity as per algorithm written in [mshsayem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46861397/4598752)’s answer.